# How to safely store passwords in Irssi?

Tags: linux, security, passwords, irssi

I use several IRC networks and it's unsafe to store passwords in plain text. On the other hand, typing each password after connection is uncomfortable.

How can I store passwords in encrypted file and only type database-password on Irssi startup? Do you know any scripts which provide something like that?

Comment: Alternatively, WeeChat [allows](https://weechat.org/files/doc/stable/weechat_user.en.html#secured_data) storing private data (like passwords) in an encrypted file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set up eCryptFS, encfs, or a similar encrypting filesystem. Mount it on `~/Private` or similar. Move your `~/.irssi` to the private directory and symlink it back to the old place.

```
ecryptfs-setup-private
ecryptfs-mount-private
mkdir ~/Private/config
mv ~/.irssi ~/Private/config/irssi
ln -s "Private/config/irssi" ~/.irssi
```

eCryptFS is recommended; it's in-kernel and gives fairly good performance. But there are other options as well, such as EncFS.

Comment: Robust solution and not only for Irssi. Thank you!